# spark-submit classpath issue with --repositories --packages options

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm running Spark in a standalone cluster where spark master, worker and submit each run in there own Docker container.

When `spark-submit` my Java App with the `--repositories` and `--packages` options I can see that it successfully  downloads the apps required dependencies. However the `stderr` logs on the spark workers web ui reports a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.serializer.StringDecoder`. This class is available in one of the dependencies downloaded by `spark-submit`. But doesn't look like it's available on the worker classpath??

```
16/02/22 16:17:09 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.main(DriverWrapper.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper.main(DriverWrapper.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/serializer/StringDecoder
    at com.my.spark.app.JavaDirectKafkaWordCount.main(JavaDirectKafkaWordCount.java:71)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

The `spark-submit` call:

```
${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster \
--master spark://spark-master:7077 \
--repositories https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/ \
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.6.0,org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark_2.10:2.2.0 \
--class com.my.spark.app.JavaDirectKafkaWordCount \
/app/spark-app.jar kafka-server:9092 mytopic
```

Answer (score 4):

I was working with Spark 2.4.0 when I ran into this problem. I don't have a solution yet but just some observations based on experimentation and reading around for solutions. I am noting them down here just in case it helps some one in their investigation. I will update this answer if I find more information later.

- The `--repositories` option is required only if some custom repository has to be referenced
- By default the maven central repository is used if the `--repositories` option is not provided
- When `--packages` option is specified, the submit operation tries to look for the packages and their dependencies in the `~/.ivy2/cache`, `~/.ivy2/jars`, `~/.m2/repository` directories.
- If they are not found, then they are downloaded from maven central using ivy and stored under the `~/.ivy2` directory.

In my case I had observed that

- `spark-shell` worked perfectly with the `--packages` option
- `spark-submit` would fail to do the same. It would download the dependencies correctly but fail to pass on the jars to the driver and worker nodes
- `spark-submit` worked with the `--packages` option if I ran the driver locally using `--deploy-mode client` instead of cluster.
- This would run the driver locally in the command shell where I ran the spark-submit command but the worker would run on the cluster with the appropriate dependency jars

I found the following discussion useful but I still have to nail down this problem.
https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues/244#issuecomment-347082455

Most people just use an UBER jar to avoid running into this problem and even to avoid the problem of conflicting jar versions where a different version of the same dependency jar is provided by the platform.

But I don't like that idea beyond a stop gap arrangement and am still looking for a solution.

Comment: These are very interesting findings. What were your sources? I'm trying to pass a package (`spark-sql-kafka`) to a spark-shell from a jupyter notebook, but I'm struggling to make it work and I can't find much information on these options and on how they work.

Comment: @michele-piccolini - As mentioned in the answer, this was mostly based on experimentation, with a bit of informed trial and error after reading around. One post that was helpful is linked in the answer. I also did a bit of digging into the sources. I had this experience in Java, so your Python environment may give you a slightly different experience.

Comment: I faced the same problem and and I have observed like you I don't know why and how to resolve the problem except use `--jars` This is nightmare, I must resolve dependencies manually and add them to `--jars`