# spark-submit --packages is not working on my cluster what could be the reason?

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I am trying to run my spark sample postgress database read in a spark application.I gave the spark command line arguments as spark-submit --packages org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101.jdbc41.jar , but I am still getting the class not found exception. Can you please help in solving my issue ?

Comment: @himanshuIIITian bro, let me know if u can help

Answer (score 4):

A similar question is posted here [spark-submit classpath issue with --repositories --packages options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559010/spark-submit-classpath-issue-with-repositories-packages-options/55194449#55194449)

I was working with Spark 2.4.0 when I ran into this problem. I don't have a solution yet but just some observations based on experimentation and reading around for solutions. I am noting them down here just in case it helps some one in their investigation. I will update this answer if I find more information later.

- The `--repositories` option is required only if some custom repository has to be referenced
- By default the maven central repository is used if the `--repositories` option is not provided
- When `--packages` option is specified, the submit operation tries to look for the packages and their dependencies in the `~/.ivy2/cache`, `~/.ivy2/jars`, `~/.m2/repository` directories.
- If they are not found, then they are downloaded from maven central using ivy and stored under the `~/.ivy2` directory.

In my case I had observed that

- `spark-shell` worked perfectly with the `--packages` option
- `spark-submit` would fail to do the same. It would download the dependencies correctly but fail to pass on the jars to the driver and worker nodes
- `spark-submit` worked with the `--packages` option if I ran the driver locally using `--deploy-mode client` instead of cluster.
- This would run the driver locally in the command shell where I ran the spark-submit command but the worker would run on the cluster with the appropriate dependency jars

I found the following discussion useful but I still have to nail down this problem.
https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues/244#issuecomment-347082455

Most people just use an UBER jar to avoid running into this problem and even to avoid the problem of conflicting jar versions where a different version of the same dependency jar is provided by the platform.

But I don't like that idea beyond a stop gap arrangement and am still looking for a solution.

Comment: I also observed that for cluster deploy-mode of spark-submit(Spark 3 running on K8S) the driver would download the package but the executor won't. if --jars is specified, the executor will copy jars from driver. This surprised me.

Comment: @Kang I faced the same problem and and I have observed like you
I don't know why and how to resolve the problem except use `--jars`
This is nightmare, I must resolve dependencies manually and add them to `--jars`

Comment: in my case event --jars doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It will be more helpful if you can give some code snippet and explain the steps of how you are building the jar and running it on the cluster. Also, what is the mode of execution (client /cluster)? Because possible reasons for classNotFoundException can sometimes be specific to how you are making the spark-submit call.

Following code worked for me. You can give it a try.

Created below scala object file inside scala maven project in eclipse:
Code is :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SparkPGSQLConnect {

case class Projects(ID:Int, Name:String, Address:String)

def main(args:Array[String]) {
      val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster(“local[*]”).setAppName("PostGreSQLConnection")
      //val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("yarn-cluster").setAppName("PostGreSQLConnection")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext= new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val jdbcDF = sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map(
        "url" -> "jdbc:postgresql:tempdb?user=******&password=******”,
        "dbtable" -> “employee”))

    jdbcDF.show(false)
    }
}
```

After that, I tested above code locally on eclipse first to verify that the code works fine. 
Then, used maven to build the jar.

And finally ran below commands from mac terminal:
In local mode:
./spark-submit --class SparkPGSQLConnect --master local[*] --driver-class-path postgresql-42.0.0.jre6.jar ~/SPGTestClient.jar

In cluster mode:
./spark-submit --class SparkPGSQLConnect --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.executor.memory=200 mb --conf spark.executor.cores=2 --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=postgresql-42.0.0.jre6.jar”  ~/SPGTestCluster.jar

Some of the jars that I needed explicit are:
postgresql-42.0.0.jre6.jar(This I needed as I was getting: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver ERROR when trying to do spark-submit from my mac terminal).